# Where can I find out how best to use Gherkin tags?

Tags: cucumber, specflow, gherkin

I've been using SpecFlow for my acceptance tests.  This uses Gherkin (the DSL Cucumber uses).  It includes an interesting feature called "tags".  I can see the practicalities of its use, but am not sure about what might constitute good practice for using tags in BDD.

I have Googled around for help but unfortunately including the word "Tag" matches lots of non-Gherkin tags (like the ones on this page!)

I hoped to find some help on the Cucumber wiki but the [Tags](https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/tagging) topic is not yet written.

I found the statement "you can use Tags to group features and scenarios together independent of your file and directory structure" but I'm afraid I don't know what that means!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good link http://www.marcusoft.net/2010/12/using-tags-in-specflow-features.html

Comment: Per SO's answering guidelines, "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."  :D